# Third party USB Ethernet adapter won't wake up

Tags: macbook-pro, network, usb, sleep-wake, ethernet

I have a mid 2015 Retina MBP 15" and regularly use multi screens and hard wired ethernet. So I've bought a third party HandAcc USB ethernet adapter with Realtek 0x8153 chipset (the device also includes a 3 x USB port hub).

Waking up after sleep the USB hub seems to be working, but the Ethernet has disconnected and won't reconnect without hot (un)plugging. This is particularly annoying if I have hard drives connected to the hub as they will disconnect (seemingly still working after waking).

Has anyone had this or a similar problem and found a decent solution?

Comment: I also have the same problem, but resetting all the preferences (deleting them) and also resetting PRAM did not solve the problem.

Comment: I have similar issue especially when the two USB LAN adaptors in different places (e.g., home and office) have the exactly same device name. I usually disconnect from the USB hub, close the lid of the MBP, move it from/to the home/office, open the lid and log-in, connect the USB hub. Everytime I do this, I have to physically disconnect and re-connect the USB LAN adaptor to make it working. If I use differently named USB LAN adaptors, then everything works fine without physical reconnects.

Comment: I can confirm I've also had this problem. I have an Anker USB 3.0 hub, with Ethernet jack. It works fine, however, upon waking the Mac up from sleep, the Ethernet isn't recognized. The USB hub itself, and all USB devices attached, work just fine, though. I have to unplug and re-plug the USB hub, and then, it's perfect. No problem with Ethernet cable or any other USB devices at all. Looks like a driver bug in macOS. I'm running High Sierra on a 2015 MacBook Pro. It's somewhat of an annoyance, and it's a chicken and egg problem when using the Mac in lid-closed mode with an external monitor.

Comment: It won't wake up until it sees valid USB keyboard and mouse connection, so it won't wake up until I plug in the USB hub, but upon doing this, I don't have USB Ethernet until I unplug and re-plug the USB hub in again (which causes me to temporarily lose access to the Mac in lid-closed mode). Somewhat annoying, but if I do it fast enough, the Mac won't fully sleep, and it will maintain USB Ethernet connectivity.

It would make my day if Apple cared enough to actually put out a fix for this problem.

Comment: I have the same issue with a 2017 MBP with touch bar, 10.13.1 and a WavLink USBC - Ethernet/USB hub (WL-UH3031GC).  If the mac sleeps, or the screen saver kicks in, when I log back in, ethernet is often, but not always, dead (but usb always working, e.g. mouse).  I have to unplug and replug the usbc connector to get ethernet back.  This is why I prefer windows - it just works ;) . Googling around, there is no solution.  It doesnt help that with the USBC dongle plugged in, WIFI doesnt work (another common problem I hear).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot allow the Mac to sleep. That is the fix. If you do, just make it standard operating procedure to unplug and re-plug. Been using Mac Pro's for music production for many, many years. This is not a problem, it is just how they work. Same as you can't hibernate a Mac, and you can't wake one up from LAN.
What seems to work on various systems (sometimes)is to have a Mac USB Keyboard directly connected to the computer and then have your items connected to the keyboard's ports. You need a powered HUB for you can't draw power from the keyboard.